# Sorting Greed High Scores(File I/O)

Tags: c, sorting, file-io

I'm in the middle of implementing Greed(greedjs.com) in C.  How can I sort these data from highest to lowest and also how can append scores that are only qualified as top ten players?

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmoqct9yrlrb6g7/Screen%20shot%202015-05-25%20at%201.37.31%20PM.png?dl=0) what it looks like.

Here's my code so far:

```
void high_scores() {
    int c;
    char player_name[256];
    FILE * fhigh_score;
    fhigh_score = fopen("HIGH SCORES.txt", "a");
    if (fhigh_score == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
   }
   printf("Your Name:\t");
   fgets(player_name, 256, stdin);
   player_name[strlen(player_name) - 1] = 0;
   fprintf(fhigh_score, "\t%s\t%d\n", player_name, SCORE);
   fclose(fhigh_score);

   fhigh_score = fopen("HIGH SCORES.txt", "r");
   if (fhigh_score == NULL) {
       printf("Error");
       exit(1);
   }
   else if (fhigh_score) {
       while ((c = getc(fhigh_score)) != EOF)   //print file to terminal
       putchar(c);
       fclose(fhigh_score);
   }
}
```

Comment: there is no need for this line: 'else if (fhigh_score) {' because the prior 'if' already handled any error about opening the file for read

Comment: noted. but how can i sort them by whose got the highest score?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a data structure to store a player along with his score. E.g.:

```
struct Player {
    const char* name;
    int score;
};
```

then you can create an array of such structures, put all the player data from file there and the apply `qsort()` to get it sorted. You will also need a comparison function to order players by score to provide to qsort.